# Searching for the same word in a Text Box in a C# form

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm a beginner, I'm making a form to analyze keywords like *"key, form, text, array"* into **TextBox1** and see the number of keywords I have entered but count it when there is a comma in front of it, the result appears in **TextBox2** and it works

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            String count = "Keyword"; 
            count1= textBox1.Text.Length - textBox1.Text.Replace(",", "").Length;
            textBox2.Text=count1.ToString();
            textBox4.Text = count;
            if (count1 > 50)
            {
                textBox3.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
                textBox3.Text = "Your keyword is more than 50!";
            }
            else
            {
                textBox3.Text = string.Empty;
            }
           
        }
```

Now I'm confused how to analyze the same keyword in Textbox1, it's very boring when I have to research them one by one, for example *"key, form, text, key"* there are 2 words *"key"* in that **TextBox1**, and I want to display that word in **TextBox2**

First of all, thank you for sharing your knowledge

Comment: Can you share the code which is analysing the text?

Comment: @Chetan I've updated the block code above

Comment: How this code does not work as per your expectation? What output do you want? What output is generated by this code? I see that in the code you have `count` variable, but you are not using it at all. All you are doing is removing commas from the string calculating its length.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to analyze how many "keywords" there are in your textbox separated by commas.

For this you can use the Split() method, which is assigned to any string type, with the separation parameter a comma (e.g. textBox.Split(',')).

The method will return a string array, where each element of the array is a string of your text, but separated by the comma now.

With a for loop you can step through this string array and count how many of these strings are one of your keywords that you are evaluating.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).